# Error when using pip: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.0.2

Tags: openshift

Recently I receive such error when using pip:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.0.2
```

I use Application with python-2.6 cartrige.
I wonder how I can fix this problem without reinstalling application on openshift?